# subclass join component with many-to-many

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have this clases:

```
class Persona{
 id
 name
 ...
}

class Cliente extends Persona{
 Date medicalRecord
 ...
}

class Empleado extends Persona{
 Especialidad specs
 int points
 ...
}

class Especialidad{
   ...
}

class EmpleadoEspecialidad{
   long id
   Empleado emp
   Especialidad esp
}
```

I have this mapping:

```
    <class name="Persona" table="persona">
        <id name="ID" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
            <column name="persona_id" index="id_index" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>

        <discriminator column="per_tipo" force="true" insert="true" not-null="true" />
        <subclass name="Cliente" discriminator-value="cliente">
            <join table="cliente">
                <key column="cl_id" />
            </join>
        </subclass>
        <subclass name="Empleado" discriminator-value="empleado">
            <join table="empleado">
                <key column="em_id" />
            </join>
        </subclass>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

with this tables:

```
+-----------------------+
| Tables                |
+-----------------------+
| cliente               |
| empleado              |
| empleado_especialidad |
| especialidad          |
| persona               |
+-----------------------+
```

**I want to add on `Empleado` one or more objects type `Especialidad` and save each record (`empleado_id` and `especialidad_id`) on table `empleado_especialidad` and get a list of `Especialidad` direct from `Empleado` (like `List<Especialidad> getListOfEspecialidad()`)
How can I archieve this?**

I want many-to-many because, in some part of my application I have to list all `Empleado` from certain `especialidad`.

I tried with this:

```
<component name="component" >
    <list name="list" table="empleado_especialidad" cascade="all">
        <key column="em_id" />
        <index column="es_id" />
        <one-to-many class="Especialidades" not-found="ignore" />
    </list>
</component>
```

inside join of subclass `Empleado`, but each records goes to table `especialidad` where I have a list (configurable by user) of object `especialidad` and I can't use same `especialidad` on more than one `Empleado`.

I want to have on database this case:

```
Persona
id:1 Name:Emp1
id:2 Name:EmpOfMonth

Empleado:
id:1 points:10
id:2 points:5

Especialidad
id:1 name:Especialidad1
id:2 name:EspecialidadX
id:3 name:Especialidad2
id:4 name:EspecialidadN

EmpleadoEspecialidad
emp_id:1 esp_id:1
emp_id:1 esp_id:3
emp_id:2 esp_id:2
emp_id:2 esp_id:1
emp_id:2 esp_id:3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was change this:

`<one-to-many ... />`

to this

`<many-to-many ... />`